# Why can't I unhide objects in 2.8 that were hidden in 2.79 blend files?

Tags: objects, 3d-view

Whenever I open a blend file that's from 2.79 in 2.8, all of the hidden objects from the blend file are grayed out but I can't unhide them. But other times layers from 2.79 that become collections are having the same problem of being grayed out even though they're not hidden in 2.79. Is this just a bug? I cant find an answer for it anywhere online. They do appear in the render, just not in the viewport window

Answer (score 5):

When hiding an object in Blender 2.79 this is indicated by the eye icon in the outliner.

[image: Outliner 2.79]

In Blender 2.8x the eye icon has a different meaning. It indicates that the object is hidden in the current view layer (*Hide in Viewport*), whereas the option in 2.79 had a global effect. Hence, when loading an old file from 2.79, it is treated as *Disable in Viewport* (Monitor icon) instead. The difference between the two is explained in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/147229/whats-the-disable-in-viewports).

> The *Hide in Viewport* option is just applied for the current view layer, whereas *Disable in Viewports* is global and applies to all view layers and viewports.

In order to change the visibility for the hidden object you need to enable the setting to show the *Restriction Toggles*.

[image: Restriction Toggles]

Afterwards you can change the visibility in the outliner and the object will appear in the viewport(s) again. The effect of the restriction toggles is documented in [Blender's manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#restriction-columns).

[image: Disable in Viewport]

The same options exist for the collections as well. Additionally a collection can be excluded from the view layer by unticking the checkbox in front of its name.

More information about this topic is available on the following pages:

- [View Layers and Collections](https://code.blender.org/2017/09/view-layers-and-collections/) - An introduction to the concept in Blender 2.8x
- [Blender 2.8: View Layers and Collections](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Layers) - Release notes for Blender 2.80