# What's the 'disable in viewports'?

Tags: outliner

[image]

I don't know difference between 'hide in viewport' and 'disable in viewports' in Blender 2.8 outliner.

What's the precise function of 'disable in viewports'?

And if possible, please explain the precise function of 'Holdout' to me too.

Comment: The short description is provided by the documentation, but a proper answer should show the effects of these options and use cases, hence this is only a comment  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/outliner.html#restriction-columns

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The *Hide in Viewport* option is just applied for the current view layer, whereas *Disable in Viewports* is global and applies to all view layers and viewports.

The change for *Hide in Viewport* is limited to the view layer as seen below

[image]
[image]

---

Activating *Disable in Viewports* in *View Layer* also affect *View Layer.001* and all other view layers.

[image]

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/141145/15543 for latest version.

Answer (score 1):

I found nice [illustration](https://cgcookie.com/lessons/hide-vs-disable-from-viewport#) of answer to this question

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/178824)